# Рестарт приложения

Tags: java, android, activity, kotlin, espresso

Как возможно до начала своих тестов сделать рестарт приложения или же убить свою активность? Потому как если этого не делать, то данные который я ввожу в DatePicker остаются неизменными и для следующих тестов.

На данный момент пробую реализовать нечто [подобное](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597080/reset-app-state-between-instrumentationtestcase-runs):

```
@Rule @JvmField
val mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(SignActivity::class.java, false, false)
```

После чего в аннотации @Before использую :

```
@Before
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun setUp() {
    DatabaseTestTools.clearDatabase()
    mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null)
}
```

К сожалению данные всё равно остаются. 
Также пробовал обращаться к текущей активости после чего пробовать её уничтожить:

```
CurrentActivityUtil().activityInstance?.finish()
```